# Add Application to Speech Server using Code

Tags: c#, vbscript, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am trying to add a Speech Server Application through Code using Vbscript. Below is Vbscript.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\MSSV2")
Set objPeerClass = objWMIService.Get("Application")
Set objPeer = objPeerClass.SpawnInstance_()
objPeer.Name= "ApplicationOne"
objPeer.Put_
wscript.echo "Created Application= " & objPeer.Name
```

This Script gives Error Number 80041031. Please help me to remove this Error.

Also please provide C# Code if it can be used to add Application to Speech Server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on the error code 80014031

WBEM_E_INVALID_PROPERTY 2147749937 (0x80041031) Property type is not recognized.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

My assumption from this is that you are using a property which is not used in VBScript, I would suggest checking the properties you have declared.

Comment: It looks like this Error is not pointing to exact Issue. Same kind of Code worked when I tried to add Sippeer Object.